how to access current value of use memo inside useMemo
const appendedFormattedOptions = useMemo(() => {
        const mergedOptions = [
            ...appendedFormattedOptions,
            ...formattedOptions,
        ];
        return mergedOptions;
    }, [formattedOptions]);

I need to access the current value so I can append to it. some thins line (prev)=>[...prev,...new]

If this value of yours decides how the UI looks it can be done using useState. Why have you used useMemo in this case? Adding that details will enrich the question and help us answer better
